# Using Ebean View `@View` without duplicating models

Tags: java, playframework, orm, ebean

I am trying to create Ebean views on tables based on a simple join and I am running into issues when I try to `extend` the `Model` for the base table.

*The Views fields and the Models fields are the exact same.*

My table Model looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "assets")
public class Asset extends EnvironmentModel<Integer> {
    @Id
    @Column
    @PrimaryKey
    @Attribute(index = 0)
    private int assetId;
    @Column
    @Attribute(index = 1)
    private String make;
    etc...
}
```

That works just fine.

Now what I am trying to to do with the `View` is:

```
@View(name = "assets_view")
public class AssetView extends Asset {
}
```

I thought I might be able to do this because the `AssetView` and the `Asset` having the same exact fields.

When I do it this way I get the exception: 

`Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: models.asset.AssetView is NOT an Entity Bean registered with this server?`

So my next attempt was to add the `@Entity` annotation to the View class. e.g.

```
@Entity
@View(name = "assets_view")
public class AssetView extends Asset {
}
```

I get the following exception when compiling: 

`Error injecting constructor, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Checking class models.asset.AssetView and found class models.asset.Asset that has @Entity annotation rather than MappedSuperclass?`

But I can't remove the `@Entity` annotation from my `Asset` class because I need that to do inserts.

**My questions is:** 
Is there any way to a have a view and a table share the same model, so I can query from the view and insert/update into the table?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found an answer and I don't know if this is obvious.

Basically, I just made my base class a `@MappedSuperClass` e.g.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class _Asset extends EnvironmentModel<Integer> {
    @Id
    @Column
    @PrimaryKey
    @Attribute(index = 0)
    private int assetId;
    @Column
    @Attribute(index = 1)
    private String make;
    etc..
}
```

Then I extended my `Asset` table and `AssetView` from that Mapped super class e.g.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "assets")
public class Asset extends _Asset {
}
```

--

```
@Entity
@View(name = "assets_view")
public class AssetView extends _Asset {
    public static final Model.Find<Integer, AssetView> finder = new Model.Finder<>(AssetView.class);
}
```